# Code for finding $a$ and $b$ such that $a b = 1 \mod 4$

Tags: number-theory

I need to find $a$ and $b$ such that $a b = 1 \mod 4$?
I do not know how to write the code. Could someone help me?

Comment: How about {a->1,b->1}?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It's an instance that solves your problem, as you stated it.

Comment: `FindInstance[Mod[a*b, 4] == 1, {a, b}, Integers, 4]`

Answer (score 2):

There are an infinite number of `{a, b}` pairs. Some examples,

```
ex = {a -> #[[1]], 
    b -> #[[2]]} & /@ (Select[Table[FactorInteger[4 n + 1], {n, 20}], 
     Length[#] == 2 &] /. {b_?NumericQ, e_?NumericQ} :> b^e)

(* {{a -> 3, b -> 7}, {a -> 3, b -> 11}, {a -> 9, b -> 5}, {a -> 3, 
  b -> 19}, {a -> 5, b -> 13}, {a -> 3, b -> 23}, {a -> 7, b -> 11}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
And @@ ((Mod[a b, 4] == 1) /. ex)

(* True *)
```

Or

```
ex2 = FindInstance[Mod[a b, 4] == 1 && a > 0 && b > 0, {a, b}, 
  Integers, 10]

(* {{a -> 3, b -> 327}, {a -> 2653, b -> 1}, {a -> 2553, 
  b -> 221}, {a -> 2095, b -> 3}, {a -> 2075, b -> 3}, {a -> 3023, 
  b -> 3}, {a -> 3947, b -> 3}, {a -> 3023, b -> 67}, {a -> 2527, 
  b -> 143}, {a -> 3299, b -> 3}} *)

And @@ ((Mod[a b, 4] == 1) /. ex2)

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
b = PowerMod[a, -1, 4];
```

This is true for any integer `a` such that `a` modulo 4 is not 0.

This simply finds the modular multiplicative inverse of `a` modulo 4, using `PowerMod`.